# Why doesn't Laravel send notifications from the queue?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, notifications, queue

I am using Redis as a queue driver. All notifications are successfully added to the queue. The queue handler accesses the external API, but it is disabled. At the same time, all tasks are successfully completed. I also tried using the standard "mail" channel. It doesn't work either. When I removed the `implements ShouldQueue` everything worked.

**OrderController.php**

```php
foreach ($orders as $i => $order)
{
    Notification::send($order, (new OrdersDelivered($text_template))
        ->delay(now()->addSeconds($i * 30))
    );
}
```

**OrdersDelivered.php**

```php
class OrdersDelivered extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private string $text;

    public function __construct($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function via($notifiable): array
    {
        return [WhatsappChannel::class];
    }

    public function toWhatsapp($notifiable): WhatsappMessage
    {
        return (new WhatsappMessage())
            ->to($notifiable->user_phone)
            ->text($this->text)
            ->totalOrders($notifiable->total);
    }
}
```

**WhatsappChannel.php**

```php
class WhatsappChannel
{
    /**
     * Sending notifications via the API
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return void
     */
    public function send(mixed $notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        $message = $notification->toWhatsapp($notifiable);
        MessageSender::send($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running the queue worker? Are all your jobs in the jobs table or they are successfully dispatched?

Comment: Yes, the queue worker is running, all jobs have been successfully dispatched.
Queue worker: https://ibb.co/Scq1V6k
Redis: https://ibb.co/GdtbbGL

Comment: The first recommendation is to remove the `delay()` method just for testing purposes. Instead of using `queue:work` you should use `queue:listen`, otherwise, you need to restart the worker on every notification change you do. Is there anything in `storage/logs/laravel.log` that may help us to debug? Are you sure that your settings are OK? What package are you using for sending WA messages?

Comment: A Laravel HTTP client is used to send a WA message. The logs are empty. In the settings, I set `DEBUG_LEVEL=info`. In the `send` method of the `WhatsappChannel` class, I wrote `Log::info('test')`, but there are still no logs.